# Dynamically creating HTML elements based on mySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi so currently I have a set of codes which dynamically creates HTML elements through AJAX using an external JSON data. When I created this, I wanted to store my data in an external file rather than in a database.

However, I now need to store them in mySQL so I was wondering how I can still dynamically create the HTML elements like this but now the data will be from mySQL instead of retrieving it from an external JSON file. I'm still quite new to this so I am really confused as to how to tackle this situation.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
 <script>
        $.ajax({
          url : "CR/CR_Data/CR_QuickLookData.json",
          type : "post", 
          contentType:"application/json", 
          success : function(list){           
              var divCol  = "<div class='col-sm-4 col-md-4'>";
              var divWell = "<div class='well' style='position:relative'>";
              var divClose = "</div>";

              console.log(list);

                list.forEach(function(obj, index) {

                //console.log(obj); 

                var title     = "<h5>"      + obj.title    + "</h5>";
                var linkStart = "<a href='" + obj.imagePath + "' rel='lightbox' title='" + obj.title + "'>"
                var image     = "<img data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' class='wellImg' title='Click to enlarge image' src='" + obj.imagePath + "'/>"
                var desc      = "<p>"       + obj.desc + "</p>";
                var linkEnd   = "</a>";

                var div = divCol    +
                divWell     +
                title       +
                linkStart        +
                image       +
                desc +
                linkEnd     +
                divClose +
                divClose;

               $("#CR").append(div); // insert the div you've just created

               })
            }
        });
      </script>
```

JSON Data:

```
 [  
        {  
          "team":"Team Name",
          "title":"Title",
          "filePath":"#",
          "imagePath":"image path",
          "desc":"Data Description"
        },
        {  
          "team":"Team Name",
          "title":"Title",
          "filePath":"#",
          "imagePath":"image path",
          "desc":"Data Description"
        },
        {  
          "team":"Team Name",
          "title":"Title",
          "filePath":"#",
          "imagePath":"image path",
          "desc":"Data Description"
        }
]
```

When I tried pulling my data using PHP and encoding it to JSON, it gave me this result and it did not create any of the HTML elements needed.

[image]

Comment: You can use PHP to format your data from MySQL to JSON data,

then in your URL, you can do something like, url : "CR/CR_Data/CR_QuickLookData.php"

Comment: Can you post a sample of your JSON data?

Comment: @PhilipBorbon Hi I've updated my post with the JSON data

Comment: @PhilipBorbon when I format it with PHP, where is the JSON data saved to?

Comment: You can save your data in MySQL database, then you can query/pull your data using PHP from MySQL database

Comment: I posted an answer that might help you get started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a MySQL table like this,

```
CREATE TABLE `record` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team` TEXT NULL,
  `title` TEXT NULL,
  `filePath` TEXT NULL,
  `imagePath` TEXT NULL,
  `desc` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Then you can use this query to insert your data,

```
INSERT INTO `record` (`team`, `title`, `filePath`, `imagePath`, `desc`) VALUES ('Team Name', 'Title', '#', 'image path', 'Data Description');
```

After that, you can create a PHP file to pull your data and print it in JSON format,

You can give the PHP file a filename like,

```
CR_QuickLookData.php
```

With PHP code,

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT team,title,filePath,imagePath,`desc`  FROM record";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$list = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $list[] = array (
        'team' => $row['team'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'filePath' => $row['filePath'],
        'imagePath' => $row['imagePath'],
        'desc' => $row['desc']
    );
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);


echo json_encode($list);
```

Then in index.html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="CR"></div>
    <script>
        $(window).ready(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url : "CR_QuickLookData.php",
                type : "post", 
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(list){           
                    var divCol  = "<div class='col-sm-4 col-md-4'>";
                    var divWell = "<div class='well' style='position:relative'>";
                    var divClose = "</div>";

                    list.forEach(function(obj, index) {
                        var title     = "<h5>"      + obj.title    + "</h5>";
                        var linkStart = "<a href='" + obj.imagePath + "' rel='lightbox' title='" + obj.title + "'>"
                        var image     = "<img data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' class='wellImg' title='Click to enlarge image' src='" + obj.imagePath + "'/>"
                        var desc      = "<p>"       + obj.desc + "</p>";
                        var linkEnd   = "</a>";

                        var div = divCol    +
                        divWell     +
                        title       +
                        linkStart        +
                        image       +
                        desc +
                        linkEnd     +
                        divClose +
                        divClose;

                        $("#CR").append(div); // insert the div you've just created
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @nurul98, sorry about that, I missed a comma, I updated the PHP code

Comment: No worries. However, I encountered another problem as I am not able to get the desired output as it did not create any of the HTML elements. I added a picture to show the output in my original post

Comment: Do you want PHP to write HTML or do you want to use JS to write your HTML?

Comment: I want to use JS to write my HTML like how I did using the external JSON data

Comment: If you still want to use your JS script, 

you'll be needing two pages, a page that contains your JS script,
and another page to serve your JSON data

Comment: Would you mind giving me a head start? I'm really confused but I really appreciate your help thus far!!

Comment: @nurul98, I updated my answer with a sample index.html, just take note that you need two files, **CR_QuickLookData.php** and **index.html** for this to work

Comment: Thank you so much you're a life saver!!